# Why is Pexpect intermittently hanging (not detecting EOF) after executing certain commands?

Tags: python, spawn, pexpect

**Context:**

I have some code written using `pexpect`, whose job is to give "live" output of a command. I.e. print something out when a command generates some output, or soon after, rather than waiting until the command completes and then interacting with its output.

All I'm doing is starting and stopping a service. I do this by `spawn`ing the process, and then outputting each line as it is printed, like so:

```
def watch(process):
    output = ""
    while True:
        try:
            line = process.read_nonblocking(timeout = -1)
            print(line, end ="")
            output += line
        except pexpect.EOF:
            break
    del process
    return output

while True:
    print("IN 1")
    process = pexpect.spawn("service",["zend-server", "stop"], timeout = None)
    watch(process)
    print("OUT 1")

    print("IN 2")
    process = pexpect.spawn("service",["zend-server", "start"], timeout = None)
    watch(process)
    print("OUT 2")
```

This code should just loop the service: start it and stop it over and over, printing the output of the start/stop as it goes. It prints the output fine. However, it eventually hangs right before "OUT 2". I can view the output, and see the `service` call stop its execution. The `watch` function never raises an EOF and exits, however.

This doesn't happen with every service. Some services loop indefinitely. `zend-server`, however, along with a few other unrelated commands, fail intermittently in the same way.

By "eventually hangs", I mean that it starts/stops the service a few (variable on each run) times, and hangs. It usually gums up after 4-6, though never on the first call--always at least on the second (hence the `del` statement; I figured I'd play it safe).

Python 2.6.6, CentOS (64) 6.3, Pexpect 2.3-6, FWIW

**Question:**

Why is `pexpect` hanging on certain commands? How should I resolve this issue?
Using timeouts isn't a feasible solution, as some of these commands really can run for an arbitrarily long time. `service zend-server stop` is just the one I picked for an example because it doesn't take that long, and I can observe it finishing.

**What I've Tried:**

I've tried replacing the `watch` method with the following, which uses `expect('\n')`, but the results are the same: a variable number of restarts, and then an eventual hang.

I can also add `pexpect.EOF` into the array that is `expect`ed along with `\n`, and handle the return value to break out of the loop, it still hangs in the same place.

```
def watch2(process):
    output = ""
    done = False
    while True:
        try:
            if not process.isalive():
                line = process.readline()
                done = True
            else:
                process.expect(['\n'])
                line = process.before
             print(line)
            output += line
            if done:
                raise pexpect.EOF(0)
        except pexpect.EOF:
            break
    del process
    return output
```

Comment: Why are you using `pexpect` when you're not doing anything interactive with the subprocess? `subprocess` from the stdlib would suffice if you're only interested in output.

Comment: It's a simplified example. In the production version, there are calls to `expect` etc, but the stripped-down example I submitted doesn't work correctly on its own.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem using this code. I'm not sure the code is the problem. Perhaps you just aren't getting any output from the zend server?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a buffering problem where pexpect is waiting for more data. You could try disabling buffering by passing `maxread=1` to `pexpect.spawn()`